# Incorrect SQL syntax error ADO.NET

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

When I try to run this i get an SqlException with the message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'."

```
120: cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE PROCEDURE FindState @Name nvarchar(50)
     AS SELECT IDState FROM State WHERE Name=@Name";
121: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Stack trace:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at xxx.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\xxx\Program.cs:line 121
```

However I tried copying the SQL command directly in a SQL query and executing it and it worked. (it created the procedure)

To give you some context here is a little bigger section of the code

```
SqlParameter stateName = new SqlParameter();
stateName.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
stateName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
stateName.ParameterName = "@Name";
stateName.Size = 50;
Console.Write("Enter state name: ");
stateName.Value = Console.ReadLine();
cmd.Parameters.Add(stateName);

cmd.CommandText = @"IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name='FindState' AND type='P') DROP PROCEDURE FindState";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE PROCEDURE FindState
@Name nvarchar(50)
AS
SELECT IDState FROM State WHERE Name=@Name";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "FindState";
sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (sdr.HasRows)
{
  while (sdr.Read())
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ID state " + stateName.Value + " is " + sdr[0]);
  }
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("No such state exists");
}
sdr.Close();
```

Comment: No erorr message (with stack trace), no line number and code that does not clean up Parameters - voting to Close.

Comment: How about this CREATE PROCEDURE FindState
(@Name nvarchar(50))
AS
SELECT IDState FROM State WHERE Name=@Name  Please note the open and close curly braces before and after stored proc parameters

Comment: Tried putting curly braces around the parameter but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.
The parameter was added to the SqlCommand before creating the procedure.
I moved this line down and now it works

```
cmd.CommandText = @"CREATE PROCEDURE FindState @Name nvarchar(50) AS SELECT IDState FROM State WHERE Name=@Name";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "FindState";
cmd.Parameters.Add(stateName);
sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: That's one of the reasons I would recommend **not** to "recycle" `SqlCommand` objects - use one per job you need to do (one for the `CREATE PROCEDURE`, and another one for calling that procedure)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SqlParameter stateName = new SqlParameter();
stateName.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
stateName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
stateName.ParameterName = "@Name";
stateName.Size = 50;
Console.Write("Enter state name: ");
stateName.Value = Console.ReadLine();
cmd.Parameters.Add(stateName);

cmd.CommandText = "IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name='FindState' AND type='P') DROP PROCEDURE FindState";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandText = "CREATE PROCEDURE FindState
@Name nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT IDState FROM State WHERE Name=@Name";
END

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandText = "FindState";

sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (sdr.HasRows)
{
  while (sdr.Read())
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ID state " + stateName.Value + " is " + sdr[0]);
  }
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("No such state exists");
}
sdr.Close();
```